# why instance.attribute = value can work while __set__ method is not implemented in property?

Tags: python, properties, descriptor

I am getting through the property to study descriptor protocol, and I am writing my own property like this:

```
class my_property(object):
    def __init__(self, fget=None, fset=None, fdel=None, doc=None):
        self.fget = fget
        self.fset = fset
        self.fdel = fdel
        if doc is None and fget is not None:
            doc = fget.__doc__
        self.__doc__ = doc
    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        if obj is None:
            return self
        if self.fget is None:
           raise AttributeError("unreadable attribute")
        return self.fget(obj)

    def setter(self, fset):
        return type(self)(self.fget, fset, self.fdel)

class test_my_property(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self._val = value

    @my_property
    def val(self):
        return self._val

     @val.setter
     def val(self, value):
         self._val = value

def main():
     c = test_my_property(5)
     print c.val
     c.val = 10
     print c.val
     print type(c).__dict__['val'].__set__
```

And I get:

```
5
10
AttributeError: 'my_property' object has no attribute '__set__'
```

My question is, since "__set__" is not defined, then how "c.val = 10" can work?
if "__set__" is inherited from object by my_property, then, why it report the AttributeError?

Comment: Your implementation of ``setter`` is wrong. What you have implemented here is only half of how a property behaves. See: [Properties](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html#properties)

Comment: It's probably worth noting that your ``setter`` only ever gets called once and not when you set the value of the property. See also @Jared's response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Jared's answer is correct. `__set__` is not inherited from object. I'll try to explain in another way, which might be clearer.

First, as you already understand, if your descriptor *do* have a `__set__` method, it gets called when running `c.val=10`.  That means the interpreter looks for the `__set__` method, and if it founds it, it treats it as a descriptor, by calling it.

Now, since `my_property` does not have a `__set__` method, it won't get the descriptor treatment when running `c.val=10`. The interpreter falls back to the "standard" treatment, which is roughly equivalent to `c.__dict__['val']=10`.

You can easily verify that using:

```
print c.__dict__  # no 'val'
c.val = 10
print c.__dict__  # 'val' was added
```

Now, the 'val' in `c.__dict__` (at object level) overshaddows your property (which is defined at class level), and will get used when accessing `c.val`.

If you want to *forbid* assignment to your property, you'd need to do it explicitly. You'd need to define a `__set__` method and raise an error in it.

Comment: Thanks very much, @shx2. It's more clearer now. So, the key point is, when assign a new value to a descriptor object, the __set__method should  be present. Otherwise, it will be treated in a "stand" way. Right?

Answer (score 1):

`__set__` is *not* inherited from object. Getting and setting `val` attribute works because when accessing an attribute of an object, first the instance will be checked, *then* the class. Since you set instance attribute `val`, it uses that. I think this is especially clear if you're looking at a simple example of this with no descriptors,

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     val = 5
... 
>>> f = Foo()
>>> f.val  # f doesn't have val so fallback on Foo
5
>>> f.val = 10
>>> f.val  # f now has val so use it
10
>>> del f.val  # oops what now
>>> f.val  # class again
5
```

The only difference between the above example and yours is that your class `val` is (when you finish) a property.

With all that said, you generally don't want to be naming your property the same thing as the instance attribute that will hold it's contents. The usual formulation is something like this,

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self._val = value

    @property
    def val(self):
        return self._val
```

Comment: hi, even I change the code, the same thing is happening.